# RF Circuit shows flat frequency response for BJT amplifier in LTSpice

Tags: amplifier, rf, bjt, ltspice, frequency-response

I am analyzing a signal jammer circuit for prototyping on LTSpice. The amplifier takes a square wave signal input from NE555 IC and is supposed to transmit it at ~2.4GHz using a tank circuit at collector. The whole circuit is powered by a 9V DC voltage. I'm using 2N2222 transistor for simulation to check the functionality, whereas I plan to use BFU690F RF transistor for the actual circuit.

[image: Circuit Schematic]

[image: Input Signal]

I'm stuck at calculating the amplifier voltage and power gains as I'm only familiar with calculations on collector resistors and not tank circuits. LTSpice shows the following frequency response, which is a flat line at -210dB for all frequencies whereas the amplifier seems to be amplifying.

[image: Output At collector of Transistor]

[image: The frequency response at collector]

Is it the case that 2N2222 is not working on LTSpice in this frequency range or is there a more serious design issue?

EDIT :

1. Figure 2 is measured between C1 and Q1
2. Figures 3,4 are measured between Q1 and C3

Comment: Use node alias names not n00x because they are meaningless.

Comment: @Andyaka Have included the details in edit.

Comment: The simulation works good, the NE555 produces a signal of around 2 MHz, the small capacitor C6 (2 pF) is absurd, dominant is the chip pin capacitance. The switching edges produce some higher frequency ringing in the RF tank. I expect, a real world circuit would do nearly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by replacing the NE555 circuit with a square wave voltage source as AC analysis requires you to have one or more independent sources with "AC" flag enabled.

Comment: LTspice should've thrown an error saying `No AC stimulus found`.  Did that not happen for you?

Answer (score 4):

"Is it the case that 2N2222 is not working on LTSpice in this frequency range". I don't know. A 2222 won't work in real life at 2.4 GHz, so, to the extent that LTspice is managing to simulate reality, it shouldn't work in LTspice.